# How do I stop a CoroutineCancellationException from causing an activity to not finish?

Tags: android, kotlin, crashlytics, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting quite a bit of fatal crash reports in Crashlytics, which seems to be caused by a coroutine cancelling.  And I have no idea on how to remedy it, and have been unable to reproduce it.

The error in Crashlytics is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {...ui.main.MainActivity}: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelled}@1ad5bcf
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4682)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4700)
       at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:39)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

and

```
Caused by kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled
```

My `MainActivity` doesn't `SupervisorJob`, but all my `Fragment`'s extend a base class that has a `SupervisorJob`.  The base fragment also calls `SupervisorJob.cancelChildren()` in the `onStop` method.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Or even how to gather more information about where/why it's happening?  I haven't been able to reproduce it myself, but it is happening quite a bit in the field.

Comment: did you cancelled the jobs in your destroy method of your activity / fragment ?

Answer (score 1):

**Unable to destroy activity** is telling you that the onDestory method cannot finish.

**Caused by kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled** is telling you that you are interacting with a job but shouldn't be because it was cancelled.

Rather than using `SupervisorJob.cancelChildren()` you should rely on [structured concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952), instead. Meaning that every one of your jobs should be launched from a scope that is cancelled when your activity or fragment are destroyed.